# Read excel data into gridview directly and show complete data with more than 255 characterin a column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, excel

Reading excel from program and showing excel data into the grid view, but the grid is showing only 255 character where as the actual data column holds more than 900. Need to show the 900 characters ina column inside gridview

Comment: Your question is skipping a step. The Excel column has 900 characters. The `GridView` is showing 255. Are you reading 900 characters but unable to display them, or is the problem that you're only reading 255 (and if that's how many you read, that's all you can display?) Is this ASP.NET, SQL Server, or Excel? I can see how it might be about two of those things, but not all three.

Answer (score 0):

Max Column width in excel is 255 characters, you can't add more than that. I recommend to divide your field in 4 and insert then in diferent fields.